# Help identify an insect on a cactus

Tags: identification, pests, succulents, cactus

I found this insect on my *Echinopsis sp.* It sort of looks like a tick, but what would a tick be doing on a cactus? What is it, and is it harmful?
[image]

Comment: What size is it?

Comment: @GrahamChiu: A couple of millimeters long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a Red Velvet Mite to me, although the pic's not entirely clear. If it is, they're arachnids and predators on other arachnids when mature, when young they may be parasitic, also on arachnids. Generally found in the soil, but they won't cause any harm to your plant https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trombidiidae

Answer (score 1):

If it's 1-2 mm in size them it's probably a whirligig mite [How helpful are whirligig mites?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/24112/1894) . Spider mites are .5 mm long and generally need magnification to see.

https://bugguide.net/node/view/94328